# Stack Overflow Required external JavaScript Issue

Tags: antivirus, malware-detection

I received this error message "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load" and was unable to comment (and more) in stackoverflow. There were lot of fixes in internet. Sometimes too many recommendations hide the right answer from searcher.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: Where should it go then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js** . It will take you to **http://download.cloudantivirus.com/eng/malicious/?id=antiphishing-vmninternethelper1_1dn&url=ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js** . Check the "I understand that visiting the page could infect my computer." check box and click **Continue** hyper link. After that if you do CTRL + F5 on stackoverflow page, it should not show the error. Thanks.

Ravi

Comment: Seems a bit contrived.  Perhaps a little narrative behind this is needed here?